# How to pass recyclerview items to another activity.

Tags: android

In my Android app I have a recyclerview which contains a list of items.  Each item has two textview and one button.  How can I code that button such that when a user click on that button that item adds to Listview of Cartactivity(Which is another activity). 
I am using JSON and MYSQL to populate the recyclerview list.

Comment: What you have tried? share your code

Answer (score 0):

A really simple solution will be to create a singleton class which will contain all the items that you have added. For example, you can create a class called *CartItems* which will have a list of *CartItem*. In your *CartActivity* you can access the object of *CartItems* and do whatever you want with it.

Just some high-level code

```
public class CartItems {
    static CartItems cartItems;

    List<CartItem> items;

    public static CartItems getInstance() {
        //Return your singleton object
    }

    public void addItem(CartItem item) {
        //Add item to your list
    }

    //Add other methods for your use
}

public class CartItem {
    //Data members

    //Member functions
}
```

In your *CartActivity* you can call **CartItems.getInstance()** to get all the added items and proceed with whatever you want.